# automatically switch from and then to git branch without losing topic changes

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash

I got a cronjob to run a test against my master branch during my break. First thing, it checks out master. Let's assume I was checkout to `topic` when I left with some uncommitted changes. I'd like to ensure when I get back, the check is done & topic branch is checked out & as it was when I left.

```sh
[programmatically check if you need to stash anything and do so if needed]
git checkout master 
[do your thing]
git checkout - [and nicely unstash changes if there were any. Do not blindly unstash old stashes otherwise.]
```

Comment: Look into using `git stash`, or create a worktree, or maybe just commit your intermediate work.

Comment: I recommend using a separate worktree (see `git worktree add`).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

- the best way is to commit your changes,
- the next best thing is [git stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) (guide by Atlassian).

If you're not ready to commit your changes on your branch `a` then create a new branch (`git checkout -b feature-x-2` = done). It's fast and it means that you will never loose these changes. You can push the changes and continue on another machine or share the unfinished work with someone else.

Stash is OK too but it's local only.

Comment: The only tricky thing about committing is my pre-commit hooks which can be pedantic and could prohibit a range of auto-commits. I agree that taking them onto another branch can be helpful as well.

Comment: The `-n` option could be used since you may be committing work in progress. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--n).

Answer (score 0):

There are very good suggestions in the replies. I liked worktree solution and here's the function I coded up followed by a use case if it's of any use to anyone:

#### create test repo

```sh
mkdir repoparent
cd repoparent
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
touch README; git add .; git commit -m "first commit"
git checkout -b topic
touch NEWS
git add .
git branch
git status
```

#### worktree function

```sh
# usage: testbranch [TESTDIR-BASENAME-IN-PARENT] [BRANCH]
function testbranch(){    
    ## directory where I want the repo to be cloned and linked
    #TEST_DIR="../crontest"
    TEST_DIR=$1
    ## remove TEST_DIR if it exists for any reason
    rm -rf $(.git/worktrees/$TEST_DIR)
    ## create TEST_DIR relative path which is in parent dir
    TEST_DIR_REL=../$1 
    printf "\nTEST DIR: $TEST_DIR_REL\n"
    ## the branch I'd like to checkout in the cloned repo
    #BRANCH='master'
    BRANCH=$2
    printf "\nBRANCH: $BRANCH\n"

    ## clone and link the repo in $TEST_DIR and checkout $BRANCH
    ## adding --force forces even if $BRANCH is checked out in another worktree.
    ## Might require care.
    rm -rf $TEST_DIR_REL
    git worktree add $TEST_DIR_REL $BRANCH --force
    ## cd to the cloned repo
    cd $TEST_DIR_REL
    # [do stuff & save outside the cloned repo which will be deleted], e.g.:
    printf "\nWe are now on worktree and checked into: "
    printf "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\n"
    ## cd to the original repo
    cd - ## assumes no cd has occurred in the main code
    ## remove the cloned repo
    rm -rf $TEST_DIR_REL
    ## IMPORTANT: keep git posted that you have removed it
    git worktree prune
    printf "\ntest successfully concluded\n"
}
```

#### use case

```sh
testbranch foo master
```

#### clean up

```sh
## clean up
cd ...
rm -rf repoparent
```

Comment: I think no need to delete the worktree, just do something like:
`git worktree add --detach $destPath $HashToBuild` then `git checkout  --progress --force $HashToBuild` and finally `git clean -fdx`